# How to move Preview window to other desktop in MacOS?

Tags: macos, preview, desktop

I know how to do this with regular application windows, you just drag the window to the edge of the screen until it moves to the next desktop.

This does not work with the Preview window.

Is there a way to force it to the other desktop?

Comment: Works for me. Did you try the alternative - hold the title bar & hit the key command for the space you want to go to?

Answer (score 1):

I use the "3-finger-pushup" method for this;

1. Make sure you have "Mission Control" enabled

[image]

2. Execute the "3-finger-pushup" move; the menu bar is replaced with a list of your desktops:

[image]

3. Select one of the app windows & drag it to any desktop you like.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it through Mission Control. Press the Mission Control button and drag the preview to the other desk.